# How to do work with custom module Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, admin-panel

I want to attach my template and block to custom module but how to manage it? I want to just print simple hello there with proper layout in admin panel 
these are my files.

> app\code\local\Matrid\Feedmanager\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Matrid_Feedmanager>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Matrid_Feedmanager>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <feedmanager>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Matrid_Feedmanager</module>
          <frontName>feedmanager</frontName>
        </args>
      </feedmanager>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
<admin>
  <routers>
    <feedmanager>
     <use>admin</use>
     <args>
      <module>Matrid_Feedmanager</module>
      <frontName>admin_feedmanager</frontName>
     </args>
    </feedmanager>
  </routers>
</admin>
<global>
  <helpers>
    <feedmanager>
      <class>Matrid_Feedmanager_Helper</class>
    </feedmanager>
  </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
 <layout>
        <updates>
      <matrid>
          <file>feedmanager.xml</file>
         </matrid>
     </updates>   
    </layout>
 <menu>
 <catalog>
 <children>
   <feedmanager module="feedmanager">
     <title>Matrid_Feedmanager</title>
     <sort_order>31</sort_order>
    <children>
      <feedmanager module="feedmanager">
        <title>Manager_Items</title>
        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
        <action>admin_feedmanager/adminhtml_index</action>
      </feedmanager>
    </children>
   </feedmanager>
   </children>
   </catalog>
 </menu>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Matrid\Feedmanager\controller\adminhtml\IndexController.php

```
 <?php

    class Matrid_Feedmanager_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
     protected function _isAllowed()
        {
            return true;
        }

      public function indexAction() {

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();


      }

    }
```

> app\code\local\Matrid\Feedmanager\controller\IndexController.php

```
class Matrid_Feedmanager_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout ();
        $this->renderLayout ();
    }
    public function anotherAction()
    {
        echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}
```

> app/design/frontend/default/electronics/layout/feedmanager.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
        </reference>
    </default>
    <test_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="feedmanager/mydata" name="feed_mydata" template="feedmanager/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </feedmanager_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: You have placed your layout xml file in the frontend and there are few coding issues in your layout xml file.

Comment: i got it bro thanx for help its working now

Comment: I want to add more children under module like one manage item and other data items so what steps should i follow from beginning to add it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Backend Module You can try keeping this files

> app/code/local/Matrid/Feedmanager/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Matrid_Feedmanager>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Matrid_Feedmanager>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <feedmanager>
                <class>Matrid_Feedmanager_Helper</class>
            </feedmanager>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <feedmanager>
                <class>Matrid_Feedmanager_Block</class>
            </feedmanager>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <feedmanager>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Matrid_Feedmanager</module>
                    <frontName>admin_feedmanager</frontName>
                </args>
            </feedmanager>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <feedmanager module="feedmanager">
                <title>Feedmanager</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <feedmanagerbackend module="feedmanager">
                        <title>Backend Page Title</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_feedmanager/adminhtml_feedmanagerbackend</action>
                    </feedmanagerbackend>
                </children>
            </feedmanager>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <feedmanager translate="title" module="feedmanager">
                            <title>Feedmanager</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <feedmanagerbackend translate="title">
                                    <title>Backend Page Title</title>
                                </feedmanagerbackend>
                            </children>
                        </feedmanager>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <feedmanager>
                    <file>feedmanager.xml</file>
                </feedmanager>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Matrid/Feedmanager/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Matrid_Feedmanager_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

> app/code/local/Matrid/Feedmanager/controllers/Adminhtml/FeedmanagerbackendController.php

```
<?php

class Matrid_Feedmanager_Adminhtml_FeedmanagerbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    protected function _isAllowed() {
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('feedmanager/feedmanagerbackend');
        return true;
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_title($this->__("Backend Page Title"));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/feedmanager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <feedmanager_adminhtml_feedmanagerbackend_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="feedmanager/adminhtml_feedmanagerbackend" name="feedmanagerbackend" template="feedmanager/feedmanagerbackend.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </feedmanager_adminhtml_feedmanagerbackend_index>
</layout>
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/feedmanager/feedmanagerbackend.phtml

Simple add hello as content

> app/code/local/Matrid/Feedmanager/Block/Adminhtml/Feedmanagerbackend.php

```
<?php

class Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Feedmanagerbackend extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template {

}
```